# Почему данный код возвращает не измененный массив? PHP

Tags: php, массивы, функции

Есть такой простой код:

```
<?php

function myfun(array $arr): array
{

    foreach ($arr as $v) {

        $v = '<script>';
    
    }

    return $arr;

}

$arr = ["aaa", '<script></script>', 'bbbb'];

$arr2 = myfun($arr);

foreach ($arr as $v) {

    echo $v;

}

foreach ($arr2 as $v) {

    echo $v;

}

?>
```

Я не могу понять, почему myfun возвращает неизмененный массив? Разве здесь в параметре функции массив передается не по значению? Значит и возвращаться должен измененный?

Comment: И снова здравствуйте)

Comment: Вместо -> $v = '<script>'; Используйте $arr[$key] = '<script>';

Comment: @BigTows снова) Однако почему не работает изменение именно значения? Разве при использовании синтаксиса "foreach ($arr as $value)" $value - это не значение?

Comment: Если бы вы написали foreach ($arr as $key => &$v)  -> то $v был бы ссылкой на значение и все бы сработало) А так это просто значение из словаря

Comment: Но так яб наверное не написал, хуже читается

Comment: @BigTows странно, но в мануале при синтаксисе ($arr as $v) $v - это значение.
https://www.php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Если говорить абстрактно, то написав ($arr as $v); $v представляет собой переменную, которое хранит значение текущей интеграции массива (оно никак не связано с массивом);Ноооо   :) Сделав вот так ($arr as &$v) - добавив амперсанд, $v становится уже ссылкой на значение! И изменяя его вы меняете значение в месте, на то куда ссылалась эта ссылка, а именно массив $arr

Comment: @BigTows действительно... Интересная штука. Спасибо большое, будем знать) PHP только начинаю курить, поэтому многие нюансы, отличающиеся от других языков, мне еще не понятны. Еще раз спасибо

Comment: Та не за что) Удачи в обучении